# Power BI sort by another column having multiple values

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have an interesting scenario. I need to sort line_item by a column named line_sort. However, this sorting changes for each line item according to the reportview column. For example, If the report view is Income Source, then the line_sort for closing balance line item is 16. However if the report view is income statement, then the line_sort for closing balance line item is 8.

When we visualize this data, we apply a filter to the visual based on the report view column (income statement, income source etc) so that each visual will have unique line items and line_sort. The line_sort should not be shown in the visual.

I am using Zebra BI and normal metrix and I could not find a way to sort the visual by a column that is not present in the visual. an example of dummy data is attached

[image]

The visuals will only show Amount by line items (sorted by line_sort but not shown in the visual). Each visual will be filtered by the reportview

One way for this to achieve was to use the feature where we click on the column line_item in the data property and in the "order by" feature, and selecting the "line_sort" column. Hower, since for the same line_item "closing balance", we have multiple line_sort (per report view, 8 and 16), this feature is not working for us and is throwing an error.

Can someone please guide me how to achieve this sorting for the line items?

Comment: Disregard my previous answer. There is no solution for this. `Income Z` and `Income y` simply contradict each other. You could maybe hack it by adding addition spaces after the `Line_Item` so they are unique. It it wasn't for Z and y, then you could have a =10, z = 15, b = 20 etc....